# Unable to grant admin consent for app in Azure AD despite being Application Adminstrator

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have an account that is an Application Administrator, and with that account, we registered an App.

When attempting to add permissions both Application and Delegated, there would be a message saying it needs admin approval. When trying to give admin consent from the apps permissions page with the following image would pop up

[image: Needs admin approval]

The permissions we were attempting to give were:

-**Microsoft Graph: Reports.Read.All**

-**Office 365 Management API: ServiceHealth.read**

And these were both Application and Delegated

What Exactly is happening here?

Are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to login in your application with the Azure AD global admin account.(Application Administrator can not do this)

Or you can ask your Azure AD admin to grant admin consent on Azure portal.

Go to your application->API permissions-Grant consent.

[image]